# How to start a systemd user unit over ssh connection with correct environment variables?

Tags: ssh, systemd, environment-variables

I have a systemd --user unit that runs correctly when run from the machine's console (Arch Linux). However, when I ssh into the machine and run the same command to start the user unit, it fails. The errors are:

```
[user@remote ~]$ systemctl --user start my-user-service.service  
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory

[user@remote ~]$ systemctl --user show-environment  
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

I have `UsePAM yes` set in sshd_config.

If I add the following 2 lines to the user's `.bashrc` on the remote machine (before connecting an SSH session as that user), I can work around the problem.

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$UID"
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/bus"
```

However, that method is not mentioned in the Arch Wiki, therefore I assume using it is not recommended. I tried all the methods mentioned [at systemd/User#Environment_variables](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Environment_variables) including writing an environment generator script. I could not get any of them to work. In each case, it is the same error first shown above.

Here's a simple generator I tried: `/usr/lib/systemd/user-environment-generators/40-user-env-generator`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$UID"
echo DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/bus"
```

What would be the correct way to resolve this?

EDIT: added new info:

cat /etc/pam.d/sshd

```
#%PAM-1.0
#auth     required  pam_securetty.so     #disable remote root
auth      include   system-remote-login
account   include   system-remote-login
password  include   system-remote-login
session   include   system-remote-login
```

cat /etc/pam.d/system-remote-login

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth      include   system-login
account   include   system-login
password  include   system-login
session   include   system-login
```

cat /etc/pam.d/system-login

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required   pam_tally2.so        onerr=succeed file=/var
/log/tallylog
auth       required   pam_shells.so
auth       requisite  pam_nologin.so
auth       include    system-auth

account    required   pam_tally2.so
account    required   pam_access.so
account    required   pam_nologin.so
account    include    system-auth

password   include    system-auth

session    optional   pam_loginuid.so
session    optional   pam_keyinit.so       force revoke
session    include    system-auth
session    optional   pam_motd.so          motd=/etc/motd
session    optional   pam_mail.so          dir=/var/spool/mail standard quiet
-session   optional   pam_systemd.so
session    required   pam_env.so
```

cat /etc/pam.d/system-auth

```
#%PAM-1.0

auth      required  pam_unix.so     try_first_pass nullok
auth      optional  pam_permit.so
auth      required  pam_env.so

account   required  pam_unix.so
account   optional  pam_permit.so
account   required  pam_time.so

password  required  pam_unix.so     try_first_pass nullok sha512 shadow
password  optional  pam_permit.so

session   required  pam_limits.so
session   required  pam_unix.so
session   optional  pam_permit.so
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the PAM settings for `sshd`, i.e. `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and any file it refers to using the `@include` keyword.

There should be a `pam_systemd.so` module invoked in the session phase, like this:

```
session optional pam_systemd.so
```

Among other things, this PAM module will initialize the two environment variables `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` and `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`.

Comment: Your configuration file uses `include` in a slightly different way from what I expected. Anyway, it looks like it refers to `/etc/pam.d/system-remote-login` - check that file too. And `pam_systemd.so` works together with `systemd-logind.service` - is that service running? (Check with `systemctl status systemd-logind.service`.)

Comment: My first comment was incorrect. Deleted it. I also updated my question again with the contents of `/etc/pam.d/sshd ` as well as the referenced files.  The module you menioned, `session optional pam_systemd.so` is already referenced.

Comment: `systemctl status systemd-logind.service` is loaded & active and not showing any errors.

Comment: Note that the line for `pam_systemd.so` is prefixed with a minus sign - it silences the error messages in case `pam_systemd.so` does not actually exist on your system. So that would be the next thing to check. It should be found in `/lib/security/` (or perhaps `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/` if Arch has adopted Debian-style multi-architecture readiness).

Comment: `ls /usr/lib/security/pam_systemd.so`
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 467504 Apr 24 04:32 /usr/lib/security/pam_systemd.so`

Comment: Maybe related?
systemd/User - ArchWiki
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#pam_environment

Answer (score 1):

Notice: If everything is fine locally then the problem is connected with the other thing than `*-environment-generators`.

For a workaround from the question I suggest you replace `$UID` with `$(id -ru)` (because the env variable can be not set and use not `user-environment-generators` but `system-environment-generators` ( see https://man.archlinux.org/man/systemd.environment-generator.7 ) because the daemon itself for `systemctl --user` is run as a *system* service so it is affected by the system environment.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the SSH server is configured to use PAM modules. In */etc/ssh/sshd_config* or */etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/99-local.conf* set

```
UsePAM yes
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint.